# Can I make a message box appear if a textbox time is 5 minutes before system time?

Tags: vb.net, timer

I am trying to create a reminder system for my break schedule (because for some reason the tech company I work for does not have one in our scheduling system /facepalm)

I can make it work IF the time I write in the textbox for my break matches the system time. What I would like it to do is change it so it pops up once, 5 minutes before and then again when it matches the system time. Here is what i have so far for the on time reminder:

```
Sub Timer1Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
DaClock.Text = Format(Now, "h:mm")
```

For the sake of simplicity ^

```
If Coffee.Text = "DaClock.Text" And reminder.Checked = True Then
    Coffee.Text = (Coffee.Text + " Over")
    Coffee.Enabled  = False
    MsgBox("Break Time", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "break")
Else If Coffee.Text = DaClock.Text Then
    Coffee.Text = (Coffee.Text + " Over")
    Coffee.Enabled  = False 
End If
End Sub
```

I find that I am not able to figure out how to get the reminder to pop up 5 minutes before.

*edit* Oh it may not be relevant but DaClock is an invisible Label

**Update** 
I was able to set up a secont label and a string with 5 minutes added so the event will trigger 5 minutes early but now i am having formatting issues:

```
        Dim MyTime As String
        MyTime = TimeOfDay.AddMinutes(5)

        D5Clock.Text = Format(MyTime, "h:mm")
```

But all it shows in the Label is h:mm. If i choose not to format it and shows normally, (eg: 6:30:54 PM) but the formatting is important to make sure my break entries trigger as we are only using the h:mm (eg 6:30) in the fields.

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of Singleton?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out by running two clocks simultaneously and calling each one so it will happen 5 minutes early and then again on time.

```
        D5Clock.Text = Format(TimeOfDay.AddMinutes(5), "h:mm")
        DaClock.Text = Format(TimeOfDay, "h:mm")
```

*whew*

Answer (score 1):

While I can respect what you're doing, and especially that you progressed and just straight out beaten the shit out of your own challenge, I would like to suggest an alternative (explanations follows):

```
Public NotInheritable Class Reminder
    Private Shared _instance As Reminder

    Private Sub New()
        'hehehe Private
    End Sub

    Public Shared Function GetInstance() As Reminder
        If _instance Is Nothing Then _instance = New Reminder

        Return _instance
    End Function

    Private Async Sub RemindMe(ByVal time As DateTime)
        Dim waiting As Boolean = True

        While (waiting)
            Await Task.Delay(60000) 'This means "Check once every minute"
            If time > Now Then
                MessageBox.Show("Wake up, it's " & Now.ToShortTimeString & " !!")
                waiting = False
            End If
        End While
    End Sub

    Public Sub Dispose()
        Me.Dispose()
    End Sub
End Class
```

So... what exactly is this unholy thing? It's a [Singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern). It's a class which has only one instance, at all time - that's why the `Sub New()` is private: I don't want people to be able to instantiate this class! Except for you. You can get ONE, only one instance, by using the public function `GetInstance()` (if you ask for more than one instance, you'll always get the first one, so ask away if you feel like it).

Then you can ask it to remind you to do stuff by giving it a time when to awaken. It keeps track of your reminders on different threads, so don't worry about these hogging all your main thread's cpu. This is just a skeleton code snippet, though, and I suggest you alter it with custom messages and the like.

Don't forget to `Dispose()` of it if you want to keep your memory happy. It'll die eventually anyway when you dispose of it's parent object, but it's a healthy habit nonetheless.

It may or may not be something which will help you, and don't mind me if it's not something you want to deal with, but I felt like you might like it. Have fun!

Comment: Hey i appreciate the options for sure. the program I am writing is a very simple means of doing my job better. it saddens me that someone with my Limited knowledge of these languages feels the need to build his own tools, but I digress. I will play with it. Not sure if it will suit my needs or not but I appreciate the alternative all the same.

Comment: What's nice of this kind of implementation is that you can use one of these across another project. For an example, you can have multiple forms and whatnot and still the reminder will work without you having to micromanage it, as long as the application is still up. If you want to implement this kind of feature through a program which isn't centered around this idea, it's a good idea. I get the idea that you probably don't need much engineering, though. Your implementation is much better if it suits your needs in an easier way to maintain! Keep up the good work!